# How to retrieve the input of the first layer of the CNN model

Tags: input, conv-neural-network, layer

`I have created this model. My problem is that I need to retrieve the input of the first layer of the model . I want to pass this input to a separate module I have created. Then, the output of this module will serve as the input to the first layer of the model.`

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D,BatchNormalization,LeakyReLU,MaxPool1D,Dense,Dropout,Flatten,MaxPool1D,GlobalAveragePooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.backend import clear_session
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

def cnn_EEG_model_modified():


    clear_session()
    model=Sequential()
    Topo_Repres_Module = TRM(input_array)
    #conv 1
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=4,kernel_size=8,strides=1, activation = 'relu',input_shape=Topo_Repres_Module.shape,name = "Conv1D_1"))#1
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,strides=2,name = "MaxPool_1"))#2
     #conv 2
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=8,strides=1,activation = 'relu',name = "Conv1D_2"))#3
    model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,strides=2,name = "MaxPool_2"))#4
    #conv 3
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=8,kernel_size=8,strides=1,activation = 'relu',name = "Conv1D_3"))#7
    model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,strides=2,name = "MaxPool_3"))#8
     #conv 4
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=16,kernel_size=4,strides=1,activation = 'relu',name = "Conv1D_4"))#7
    #model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(MaxPool1D(pool_size=2,strides=2,name = "MaxPool_4"))#8
    #fully connect layers
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(units=10,activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(units=5,activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))#11

    #model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate =.0001),loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model=cnn_EEG_model_modified()
model.summary()
```

Wanna to retrieve the input of the first layer of the model do some processing on the input  Then, the output of this module will serve as the input to the first layer of the model.